# Convert properties file like the one from database into JSON format using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

*For example:*

```
activ.contributionGateway.serviceId=Service.ContributionGateway
activ.contributionGateway.url= google.com
activ.contributionGateway.connectionRetry.interval=5
activ.contributionGateway.connectionRetry.timeout=60
activ.contributionGateawy.FDG.PermissionId=6710
activ.contentGateway.serviceId=Service.ContentGateway
activ.contentGateway.url=google.com
activ.contentGateway.connectionRetry.interval=5
activ.contentGateway.connectionRetry.timeout=60
```

**the output should be like this:**

```
 {  
           "Activ":{  
              "contributiongateway":{  
                 "serviceId":"Service.ContributionGateway",
                 "url":"google.com",
                 "connectionRetry":{  
                    "interval":5,
                    "timeout":60,

                 }         "FDG":{  
                    "PermissionId":6710,

                 }
              }      "contentGateway":{  
                 "serviceId":"Service.ContentGateway",
                 "url":"google.com",
                 "connectionRetry":{  
                    "interval":5,
                    "timeout":60
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

How can I do this using python with taking care of all the curly braces as well as for all the sub elements and new elements